# negativ update rate in .world file

Tags: ros, rate, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, what does a negativ update rate in a .world file mean?
i was told that the simulation then runs as far as possible in order to provide nearly realtime simulation.But i cant find a documentation or explanation in ros or ODE. Is that true? Where can i find a documentation about that??
physics:ode
0.001
0 0 -9.8
0.0000000001
0.2
true
10
1.3
100.0
0.001
-0.1
</physics:ode>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30415/negativ-update-rate-in-.world-file/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is the case. See for example these two tickets on problems with the framerate locking mechanism (that should be fixed now): [1](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/28),[2](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5083)
Update Rate settings are also documented on the (old) [gazebo problem resolution guide](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/wiki/GazeboProblemResolutionGuide).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1